# Navigate back to the respective Fragment using up button

Tags: java, android

I have implemented Bottom Navigation with three top level destinations (one fragment for each destination): **Home**, **Search** and **Settings** respectively. In Search fragment I had search button, which up on click, takes to another activity say ActivityX. When navigated back from ActivityX using up button, it navigates to Home instead of Search. I want the up button navigate to Search. How to achieve it?

**My MainActivity:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    sp=getSharedPreferences("login_details",MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(!sp.getBoolean("login_status", false)){
        isLoggedIn=false;
    }
    else
        isLoggedIn=true;

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    BottomNavigationView bottomNav = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft1=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft1.add(R.id.container,new HomeFragment());
    ft1.commit();
    updateToolbarText("Home");
    bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            if(item.getItemId()==R.id.action_home){
                fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft1=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                ft1.replace(R.id.container,new HomeFragment());
                ft1.commit();

                updateToolbarText("Home");

            }
            if(item.getItemId()==R.id.action_search){
                fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft2=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                ft2.replace(R.id.container,new SearchFragment());
                ft2.commit();
                MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                updateToolbarText("Search");


            }
            if(item.getItemId()==R.id.action_settings){
                fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
                android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft3=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                ft3.replace(R.id.container,new SettingsFragment());
                ft3.commit();
                updateToolbarText("Settings");
            }
            return true;

        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ActivityX create intent and put string in it. The string contains information where are you comming from, ie. Search, and then startActivity(ActivityX, MainActivity).

Then in MainActivity override onResume method. In this method check if intent contains specific string you put in ActivityX. If it contains that string, start the SearchFragment

Here is my example:

ActivityX:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(FragmentTrainingDetail.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("TAG", "FragmentMyTraining");
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    if (intent.hasExtra("FragmentMyTraining")) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentMyTraining());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("my");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } else if (intent.hasExtra("FragmentPopularTraining")) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentPopularTraining());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("pop");
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is onBackpressed()  detects the action bar up button? The solution is not working for me .The app is crashing after I use this.

Comment: I was just showing my example which is similar as your problem, arrange it a little so it suits your needs. In my case i had 2 activitys. MainActivity contains 2 fragments. From each fragment you can go to second activity, but when u want to go back, you pass info, which fragment should open.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I somehow did not get solution by using intents and didn't know  what went wrong.But I got idea from your solution and I did it using shared preferences.

Comment: I got the solution but the tab indicator is not changing.Do you have any solution for that.

Comment: You are using something like this?

https://github.com/roughike/BottomBar

Maybe this helps with your problem.